# Including Angular in .NET application

Tags: angular

I wanted to include a single page Angular application inside and existing .NET application. I understand with the help of Angular elements it works well. Does it work fine if I simply copy the contents of the Angular app (index.html with the static references which we get after doing the build) to the ASP.NET page? The routing part will be managed using hash.

When I tried this, it was taking too much of time to even type something in a text field which otherwise will happen in microseconds.